# Using Println to Display results of superclass method

Tags: java

I have developed these three classes:-

**FindArea**

```
package myapp;

public class FindArea {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Figure f = new Figure(10, 10);
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(4, 4);
        Triangle t = new Triangle(4,8);
        Figure figref;
        figref = r;
        System.out.println("Area is: " + r.area());
        System.out.println(figref.area());

        System.out.println(t.area());
        System.out.println("Area is: " + f.area());
    }
}
```

**Rectangle**

```
package myapp;

public class Rectangle extends Figure {
    Rectangle(double a, double b) {
        super(a, b);
    }

    double area() {
        System.out.println("Area of Rectangle is:");
        return width*length;
    }
}
```

**Triangle**

```
package myapp;

public class Triangle extends Figure {
    Triangle(double a, double b) {
        super(a,b);
    }

    double area() {
        System.out.println("Area of Triangle is: ");
        return (width/2)*length;
    }

}
```

**Figure**

```
package myapp;

public class Figure {
    double width;
    double length;

    Figure(double dimL, double dimW) {
        width = dimW;
        length = dimL;
    }

    double area () {
        System.out.println("Unknown shape. Area cannot be defined.");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I expected the output from **FindArea** to show the following:-

```
Area is: Area of Rectangle is:
16.0
Area of Rectangle is:
16.0
Area of Triangle is: 
16.0
Unknown shape. Area cannot be defined.
Area is: 0.0
```

Instead, however, the results displayed are as follows:

```
Area of Rectangle is:
16.0
Area of Triangle is: 
16.0
Unknown shape. Area cannot be defined.
Area is: 0.0
```

Why has the `System.out.println("Area is: " + r.area());` line been ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.out.println("Area is: " + r.area());` statement is not ignored. In fact, the output of the program as it is shown is the following:

```
Area of Rectangle is:
Area is: 16.0
Area of Rectangle is:
16.0
Area of Triangle is: 
16.0
Unknown shape. Area cannot be defined.
Area is: 0.0
```

So you can see that `Area is:` is being correctly printed.

The statement `System.out.println("Area is: " + r.area());` does the following:

1. `r.area()` is first invoked.
2. This causes `Area of Rectangle is:` to be displayed first due to the statement `System.out.println("Area of Rectangle is:")`
3. The return value `width * length` is returned, in this case `16.0`. This is printed by the first `println` as follows: `Area is: 16.0`

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realise the console window had a scroll bar! A scroll up revealed the mystery output! So embarrasing! Thanks again for checking my code anyway :)

Comment: I do have another query though, if you don't mind helping me out? Does the println method call the area() function first, before printing the string?

Comment: Yes the `area()` method is called first, not because `println` itself calls it, but because `area()` is used in the argument of `println` so it needs to be invoked first.